# Mysql Left Join of 3 tables and a one being joined twice

Tags: mysql

I need to do a join of 3 tables.

They all have an ID value, the issue is:

Table 1

Is the main one, name : cnpj_cnae and the ID is CNPJ_CNAE

Table 2

I need to get four columns from this one (Up to here I already got it).
The ID here is CNPJ_CNAE

Table 3

Here's the issue. For each ID value on table 1 I can have more than 1 even 10 on this table. I need to get 4 columns from ONLY THE FIRST TWO of this table.
The ID here is CNPJ_SOCIO

The finishing table would need to look like

```
ID INFOTABLE1 INFOTABLE2 INFOTABLE3ROW1 INFOTABLE3ROW2
```

I have tried some joins, but being a relative newbie with mysql I am suffering >.<

I have tried to do this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cnpj_cnae_emp_test3 AS (
SELECT 
`cnpj_cnae_test2`.*,
`cnpj_soci`.NOME_SOCIO,`cnpj_soci`.CNPJ_CPF_SOCI,`cnpj_soci`.ID_QUALIFICACAO_REP,`cnpj_soci`.DESC_QUALIFICACAO_REP,
`cnpj_emp_02`.MUNICIPIO,`cnpj_emp_02`.BAIRRO,`cnpj_emp_02`.TIPO_LOGRADOURO,`cnpj_emp_02`.LOGRADOURO,`cnpj_emp_02`.NUMERO,`cnpj_emp_02`.COMPLEMENTO
FROM `cnpj_cnae_test2`, `cnpj_soci`, `cnpj_emp_02`
WHERE `cnpj_cnae_test2`.CNPJ_CNAE = `cnpj_soci`.CNPJ_SOCIO AND `cnpj_cnae_test2`.CNPJ_CNAE = `cnpj_emp_02`.CNPJ
);
```

The issue is this will generate extra rows for every SOCI where instead of 1 soci on each one I need 2 socis on each line.

Table 1:
[Layout of CNAE table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAizc.png)

Table 2:
[Layout of EMP table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GewMH.png)

Table 3:
[Layout of Socio table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClxqZ.png)

The resulting table would look like this:
More detailed end result [Final layout with descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MTre.png)
[Layout of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2H5Y.png)

In the end this by Owl was exactly what I needed:

```sql
WITH soci_partition AS (
    SELECT CNPJ_SOCIO
    ,NOME_SOCIO
    ,CNPJ_CPF_SOCIO
    ,ID_QUALIFICACAO
    ,DESC_QUALIFICACAO_SOCIO
    ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CNPJ_SOCIO ORDER BY IDX ASC) AS rownum
    FROM cnpj_soci
)

SELECT *                                    -- add actual columns
FROM cnpj_cnae_test2 AS cnae
INNER JOIN cnpj_emp_02 AS emp               -- left join instead? depends on table structure
    ON cnae.ID_CNAE = emp.IDX
LEFT JOIN soci_partition AS soci1 
    ON soci1.CNPJ_SOCIO = cnae.CNPJ_CNAE and soci1.rownum = 1
LEFT JOIN soci_partition AS soci2 
    ON soci2.CNPJ_SOCIO = cnae.CNPJ_CNAE and soci2.rownum = 2
```

Comment: Missing : tables structures (FK and stuff), data sample, expected output, current one with the query you wrote and this question could be answerable

Comment: Just added what the result should look like.

Comment: "I have tried some joins".  So where's the query?

Comment: This seems to be a collection of pictures.

Comment: This is almost enough to answer the question. How are you defining "first" vs "second" match?

Comment: The first match would have the lowest IDX among all matches in the Soci table.
The second match would have the second lowest.
All the ones after that can be discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got the joins/partition right, the foreign keys weren't clear.

Even if it's not perfect, hopefully this explains the general theory. Please edit in your correct answer if you end up debugging.

Also don't use old-style joins. You'll immediately fail interviews on that alone; they were deprecated 25 years ago.

```
WITH soci_partition AS (
    SELECT CNPJ_SOCIO
    ,NOME_SOCIO
    ,CNPJ_CPF_SOCIO
    ,ID_QUALIFICACAO
    ,DESC_QUALIFICACAO_SOCIO
    ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CNPJ_SOCIO ORDER BY IDX ASC) AS rownum
    FROM cnpj_soci
)

SELECT *                                    -- add actual columns
FROM cnpj_cnae_test2 AS cnae
INNER JOIN cnpj_emp_02 AS emp               -- left join instead? depends on table structure
    ON cnae.ID_CNAE = emp.IDX
LEFT JOIN soci_partition AS soci1 
    ON soci1.CNPJ_SOCIO = cnae.CNPJ_CNAE and soci1.rownum = 1
LEFT JOIN soci_partition AS soci2 
    ON soci2.CNPJ_SOCIO = cnae.CNPJ_CNAE and soci2.rownum = 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to below query

```
select * from cnae t1
left join emp t2 on t1.cnpj_cnae = t2.cnpj 
left join socio t3 on t1.cnpj_cnae = t2.cnpj_socio
group by idx_cnae ;
```

Comment: Tried running this, but... it just runs forever and never seems to result, even if I limit it to 2000 rows.

Comment: could you provide a record sample

Comment: Sorry, once again I am a bit of a newbie with Mysql... how would I do that?